# List of ports and applications

Tags: windows-server-2003, port

How do I get a list of active ports and applications using them in a Windows Server 2003 box?
Any free utilities?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) is pretty handy.

Comment: Damn - beat me to it. :) Yeah, TCPView does exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3):

`netstat -o` is already on the system.

Comment: `-a` is necessary for the listening ports to be listed as well.  `-o` will only list active connections with pid.

Comment: + 1 for netstat. I usually run netstat -a -n -o

Answer (score 0):

nmap -v *hostname*

Nmap is the most thorough port scanner ever made.

Comment: He's not asking to scan for open ports.  He's wanting to know what ports are being used by what processes on his computer.

Answer (score 0):

What about SysInternals (now Microsoft) tools like `Process Explorer` or `TCPView`?

Answer (score 0):

Another useful utility is [`fport`](http://www.foundstone.com/us/resources/proddesc/fport.htm). It's a bit like `netstat -o`, but it shows the process name and application path in addition to the PID.

Comment: fport definitely doesn't work with Win7 or Win2K8. I haven't tried it but may do the same for Win2K3.

Comment: I know it works on 2003, but you are correct for Win7 (64-bit, anyway). Thanks for the tip, I wasn't previously aware of this. It's too bad, because it's a handy little tool.